# What is the default value for "highlightAll" in Firefox's about:config?

Tags: firefox, about-config

I was trying to find a way to permanently enable "Highlight All" on the find bar, but accidentally toggled `highlightall` instead of `findbar.highlightAll`. I can't find any documentation on this, and there's no reset to default option like there is for `findbar.highlightAll`.

Does anyone know what `highlightall` (no caps) does, and what the default value should be?

[image]

Comment: Click the little trashcan to reset the value? I don't have that value at all https://i.stack.imgur.com/BZYCv.png You may well just have set up a new item that is not used at all.

Answer (score 0):

The reason you can't find any documentation on a `highlightall` (all lowercase, without any prefix) preference is that it isn't used by any recent versions Firefox.

Personally, I would click the trash can button to the right of the preference and delete it.  Or, if it makes you more comfortable, you can leave it be.  Either way, Firefox isn't using it.

As you noted, the Firefox preference with a similar name is `findbar.highlightAll`, which as of Firefox 109, has a default value of `false`.